# Add CanvasFrame (ffmpeg) in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, ffmpeg, javacv

I create a Java class using JavaCV that play a video and capture frames. The video "plays" in a CanvasFrame using ffmpeg. I want to add that canvas in a JFrame. Is that possible?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         //Create canvas frame for displaying video.
         CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("VideoCanvas"); 


         File movie_name = new File("niki.mp4");

         //Declare FrameGrabber to import video from "video.mp4"
         FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber=new FFmpegFrameGrabber(movie_name); 


          //Start grabber to capture video
          grabber.start();      

          //Declare img as IplImage
          IplImage img;

          while (true) {

           //inser grabed video frame to IplImage img
           img = grabber.grab();

           //Set canvas size as per dimentions of video frame.
           canvas.setCanvasSize(grabber.getImageWidth(), grabber.getImageHeight()); 


           //Show video frame in canvas
           canvas.showImage(img); 

           //save video frame as a picture
           cvSaveImage("capture.png", img);


           }

        }
```

Comment: Per the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/CanvasFrame.java), a CanvasFrame **is** a JFrame.

Comment: But I can not add Jbuttons:/ If I add it, it covers all canvas's window

Comment: Why not create a JPanel to hold your JButtons, and then simply add that JPanel to the contentPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH?

Comment: `"JPanel can not hold JButtons"` -- Sorry, but that just makes no sense. A JPanel can hold whatever components you give it.

Comment: ok sorry I am new in that.  I can not appear the video and buttons in the canvas. I try that you said but I have the same problem:/